# when i use android gcm in node js&express server, occur error and server was dead

Tags: node.js, post, express, google-cloud-messaging

I use nodejs&express on windows.

express version is 3.

build tool is visual studio 2015(nodejs) & express

my error message is

The program '[9492] node.exe' has exited with code -1073741819 (0xc0000005) 'Access violation'.

Specifically, I want to get data(gcm token) to use post and, send push message.

my source

**app.js**

```
app.post('/users', user.send_push_post);
app.get('/users', user.send_push);
```

**user.js**

```
   exports.send_push = function (req, res) {
    res.render('users');

};

exports.send_push_post = function (req, res) {

    // req data key, gcm token, ~~~
    if (req.body.key === '~~~~~') { 
    var gcm = require('node-gcm');

    var message = new gcm.Message();

    var message = new gcm.Message({
        collapseKey: 'demo',
        delayWhileIdle: true,
        timeToLive: 3,
        data: {
            title: 'test GCM demo',
            message: 'test',
        }
    });

    var server_api_key = '~~~~~~my api key';
    var sender = new gcm.Sender(server_api_key);

    var registrationIds = [];

        var token = req.body.push;

        registrationIds.push(token);
        sender.send(message, registrationIds, 4, function (err, result) {
            console.log(result);
        });

    }
    res.render('users');
};
```

**users.jade**

```
doctype html
html
  head
    title
  body
  form(name="add-estimation", action="/users", method="post")
        div.input
            span.label key
            input(type="text", name="key")
        div.input
            span.label push
            input(type="text", name="push")
        div.input
            span.label od
            input(type="text", name="od")
        div.input
            input(type="submit", value="sub")
```

**Strange thing is first work was fine. But when i refresh the page server is dead with error**

when i call ~~~.users, work perfecttly.

and filled up the data, then submit. fine.

then refresh or call ~~~.users... dead.

Am i missed somethings?

Comment: What version of node are you using? (Try typing `node -v` into a console.)

Comment: node version is v4.3.0... strangely, when i use this codes in the linux(likes ubuntu&centos), working perfectly!! It looks like build tool's bug or nodejs's bug in window platform. or something a my mistake.